# imagemagick Fill region outside of rectangle

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I have an image and I want to fill with some color (e.g. blue) parts of that image which are *outside* of a rectangle. Position of left upper corner and width/height of this rectangle relative to the left upper corner of the original image are known.

[image]

Here borders of the original image are in red and borders of the rectangle are in black. Blue area should be filled.

How can I do this? I tried to create a tmp image and use [a mask](https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/compose/#mask) but it seems to also fill transparent regions inside the rectangle which is not what I want.

Also, there is probably a way to do it without creating intermediate images? I'd be interested in both options though, because I'm not sure how requirements will change over time -- maybe in the future I'd have to apply some other shape (not a rectangle), so having a way to apply an arbitrary mask would be better in that case.

Example:

- image:
  [image]

- coordinates of the rectangle (assuming x axis runs from left to right, y axis from top to bottom, with `(0,0)` being left-upper corner of the original image):

  - left-upper corner `(117,-24)`
  - right-bottom corner `(1117,1676)`

Comment: Do a floodfill from some point inside that region. Since you know the region, you can compute some point such as the center of that region to start the floodfill

Comment: @fmw42 the problem is that the rectangle can intersect the original image in many different ways, e.g. it can "squeeze" in the middle of it, so there would be multiple areas to fill or an area with non-rectangular shape. It is doable but kinda difficult, I'm looking for a different solution

Comment: -connected-components can separate each region. See https://imagemagick.org/script/connected-components.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Find a colour that doesn't exist in the original image. Hint: use `-unique-colors`
- Fill/draw the black image with that colour
- Make everything that is not that colour blue. Hint: use `-fill blue +opaque THATCOLOUR`
- The blue pixels are your mask

Not sure if I have understood you correctly, but here is what I get for the first part:

```
magick 7uZfM.png -alpha deactivate -fill yellow -draw "rectangle 117,-24 1117,1676" result1.png
```

[image]

And then the second part:

```
magick 7uZfM.png -alpha deactivate -fill yellow -draw "rectangle 117,-24 1117,1676" -fill blue +opaque yellow -transparent yellow result2.png
```

[image]

Ok, now with the original image showing through:

```
magick 7uZfM.png \( +clone -alpha deactivate -fill yellow -draw "rectangle 117,-24 1117,1676" -fill blue +opaque yellow -transparent yellow \) -flatten -background magenta result3.png
```

[image]

Comment: Can you provide actual commands? I'm not sure how to apply the mask in this case

Comment: @xaxa Sure. Please provide representative input images and representative data so folks know exactly what you have available - at the moment there is only a vague summary of the general idea.

Comment: I have image file named original.png (red rectangle) and coordinates of the black rectangle left-upped corner (x1,y1) and right-bottom corner (x2,y2). Output filename should be result.png

Comment: @xaxa Please click `edit` under your image and add representative images and representative  coordinates. It wastes too much time if I guess someone has a sharp PNG and it turns out to be a JPEG where the pixels are all lossy and blurry. Or I guess they have a JPEG and they then say they have a PNG with an alpha channel I wasn't expecting. Or if I assume they measure offsets from the top-left but they use BMPs and measure offsets from the bottom-left. Or their images are floating point....

Comment: I've uploaded an example... but will this solutions depend on the quality and format of the original image? These images will be supplied by users, so I have very little control over it. Formats will probably be limited to png and jpeg, but I can't say anything about quality.

Comment: If I have misunderstood your needs, please explain what is wrong rather than downvoting and saying it is wrong. I am sure we can work together to get what you want - other folk may help too. I just chose yellow and blue so you can see what parts are affected by each command.

Comment: This is almost exactly what I need, thank you. What's missing is the the original image visible through the transparent part of the second image. Also the size of the result should be the same as the original image.

Comment: Will this work if the original image is a jpeg?

Comment: Did you use yellow because it's not in the original image or any color could be used?

Comment: I used yellow and blue and magenta because they make it easy for you to see which code is affecting which part of the output image - and also because they do not appear in the image.